# Terms for young, medium and old animal meat

Tags: single-word-requests, hyponyms

I know terms for the meat of young animals of a specific species, such as "lamb" (also the name of a young sheep) and "veal", and the meat of old animals of a specific species or set of closely related species, such as [mutton](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167738/why-is-mutton-used-for-both-sheep-meat-and-goat-meat). But are there any terms for the meat of young animals in general, terms for the meat of old animals in general, and for those in between?

For the example of how it'd be used, as mandated in the tag wiki for single word requests: I'm currently using

> Do [the aliens] want human lamb, human hogget, or human mutton?

which is probably likely to be understood, but I'd like to know if there's more accurate words to use in this context. I assume the English language doesn't have words specifically for the meat of young humans, medium aged humans or old humans, so the most accurate approach would be saying "human [generic term for young animal meat]", "human [generic term for medium aged animal meat]", and "human [generic term for old animal meat]".

Comment: Could I point out that Andrew is actually (and very specifically) wanting three words which are the age-related meat hypernyms of which *lamb, hogget* and *mutton* are respectively members? He is not asking for different ways of rephrasing his sentence, nor for words which identify humans, nor for words which identify different treatments of meat.

Comment: I'd be tempted to say: Baby/infant flesh; young adult flesh, and tough bird  :)

Comment: The discerning alien would also want to know whether the human was free-range, if it had been treated with antibiotics, and if it had been slaughtered "humanely".

Comment: I don't think such words exist. Having said that, may I suggest the term 'suckling' (as in 'suckling pig') for meat from an unweaned child.

Comment: As Zaroff in "the most dangerous game", aliens may hunt "human game: young, full-grown or elderly people". Then, you can say "*What kind of human game want aliens? Tender, red or shriveled meat.*" By the way, I don't really know if adults flesh is red or not.

Comment: @JHCL. _Suckling_ is a great suggestion for baby flesh. Adult human flesh may not need a qualifier since it would be the default. We could then have suckling human, human, and wizened human (as suggested by Mari-Lou in her answer below).

Comment: It's worth noting that creatures reared for meat don't usually reach anything approaching 'old age'. Even mutton is taken from animals who could be said to be 'barely in their prime' (from two years upwards) when their natural lifespan is 12 years or so.  The human equivalent would actually be 'young adult'.

Comment: @JHCL: That's true for the meat industry. But in bygone days, and still today in some areas, meat is not just grown. Animals that are hunted or fished (or even scavenged) are eaten, as are domestic animals (e.g. work horses) that die. In such cases, yes, old creatures too are eaten.

Answer (score 2):

What a delightfully ghoulish question :) Given the option, I'd say

1. infant flesh
2. young adult flesh
3. [wizened](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wizened) flesh

Generally speaking, beef is grouped into three classes

1. *[milk-fed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veal#Types)* veal
2. *[young](http://www.britannica.com/topic/beef)* beef
3. *[aged](http://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2015/mar/11/extreme-aged-steak-meat-with-mould-on-gourmet)* beef

Comment: Have you ever used or heard those words? Just curious Mari-Lou.

Comment: @Rathony  "Given the option, I'd say" I thought was pretty self-explanatory! I'm not in the habit of purchasing human "meat".

Comment: @ I just wanted to ask you because I have never heard of those words. :D

Comment: Aged beef is not beef from old animals. It is meat that has been aged, the classic process being _hung_.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast yes, the information is contained in the link I provided. But in the OP's context the meaning is clear, the meat is from mature cattle. Oh, *mature meat*, that could work too.

Answer (score -1):

I've never heard of meats being rated or labeled for the age of the animal. However, you could possibly use terms for the grades of meat instead of their age, like:

> prime, choice, good, standard, and utility.

Or you could creatively hint at their ages, which I think would come across:

> Do [the aliens] want human veal, human beef, or human jerky?

Answer (score -4):

I would rewrite the sentence as below:

> Do [the aliens] want kid's meat, elderly's meat, or youth meat?