# When and why did the word "pasta" become commonly used?

Tags: etymology, terminology, word-usage, historical-change, food

I remember sometime around 1980 that people started calling pasta... "pasta". I was in a used book store this past weekend and stumbled across two copies of the [*Better Homes and Gardens New Cookbook*](https://vintagecookbook.com/product-category/vintage-general-or-comprehensive-cookbooks/better-homes-and-gardens-cookbooks/), one from the early seventies and one a more recent vintage. I looked at the index from each. Sure enough, "pasta" does not have an entry in the 1970's edition, but figures prominently in the more current edition.

Who or what caused the word "pasta" to be commonly used as an umbrella term for spaghetti, farfalle, linguini, etc.?

Comment: Amazingly, nobody has mentioned the word "noodles." When I was a kid, that was the ordinary word -- lasagna noodles included. When I started hearing "pasta" I thought it was a strange attempt to make cheap, plain food sound fancy. Now the word "noodles" sounds sort of funny to me, almost a joke for its lack of class.

Comment: @Chaim This terminology seems to be quite location-dependent. In the UK, ‘noodles’ refers only to the stranded East-Asian food, _not_ to pasta (which is often not even the same shape!). Here, ‘lasagna noodles’ seems like a meaningless combination of random words, like ‘fried egg custard’ (or ‘chicken fried steak’…).

Comment: The word "pasta" does not even appear in the Compact OED, including the supplement.

Comment: See here: [link](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=pasta)

Comment: @gidds Merriam-Webster's entry for "noodle" does not give my sense, but at the bottom of the entry mentions "chicken-noodle soup," which is my sense. I also found the header "Thin Long Noodles Like Spaghetti, Angel Hair, Capellini and Spaghettini" at the Food Network (https://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/photos/pairing-pasta-with-sauce)

Comment: @Chaim Oh, I wasn't doubting your sense at all! I've seen it several times before — on this site and elsewhere — so it's clearly widely used in your part of the world. It just caused me some confusion the first few times I saw it, until I realised that the word's used differently in different places. (That's the trouble with language variations. If you've never seen a word before, your lack of knowledge is obvious; words that you _think_ you know are the really dangerous ones!)

Comment: I'm surprised to find that _noodles_ isn't mentioned (yet) on the [comprehensive translation page](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/784/translating-cooking-terms-between-us-uk-au-ca-nz) over on the ‘ Seasoned Advice’ Stack. I'll ask there.

Comment: Sticking with cookbooks -- my 1951 Joy of Cooking calls it pasta; the 1931 calls them noodles.

Comment: Sorry,Bob. Your 'around 1980' seems to me a generation too late, at least.

I don't claim to have understood anything about it and I do remember hearing of 'pasta' long before 1980.

Comment: @gidds wut. Chicken fried steak is steak that is fried in the style typical of chicken. Lasagna noodle is one single unit of lasagna. I’ve never heard of a fried egg custard but I’d suspect it also has meaning.

Comment: @Chaim I had the perception that "spaghetti noodle" had overtaken the earlier "string of spaghetti" in American English only during my lifetime (for instance Feynman refers to a "stick of spaghetti" in one of his famous home experiments rather than a "dry spaghetti noodle"). The Google nGrams appear to be in my favour [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spaghetti+noodle%2Cspaghetto%2Cstring+of+spaghetti%2Cstick+of+spaghetti&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany The OED first added *pasta* in its *A Supplement to the OED, volume III* (1982), whence it next appeared in the *OED Second Edition* (1989), and was fully revised for the *OED Third Edition* in June 2005. Its most recently modified version was published online in September 2022, and is available [here](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/138569) by paid subscription only. Citations date back only to 1830, although there is one earlier reference to it used in English from 1820 where they cite someone glossing the Italian *pasta di casa* as meaning “household paste”.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

According to Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary, the word *pasta* has appeared in English publications since at least 1847—but you wouldn't know it by checking editions of *Webster's Collegiate Dictionary* prior to the seventh edition (1963). That's when the first entry for *pasta* appeared in the *Collegiate* series, as follows:

> **pasta** *n* {It[alian], fr. L[ate] L[atin]} **1 :** a paste in processed form (as spaghetti) or in the form of fresh dough (as ravioli) **2 :** a dish of cooked pasta

Prior to the Seventh Collegiate, the only term that Webster's offered for the generic category of (usually) eggless noodles now generally termed *pasta* was *paste*, as in this relevant definition from a longer entry for that word in the *Sixth Collegiate* (1948) suggests:

> **paste**,  *n.* **1.** Dough; specif.: ... **b** Any shaped and dried dough prepared from semolina, farina, or wheat flour, or a mixture of these with water (as in macaroni, spaghetti, vermicelli), milk, or egg.

Because of confounding alternative meanings, there is little point in tracking the frequency of *paste* over the past 120 years in Google Ngram, but an expansion of the Ngram that GEdgar provides for *pasta* (blue line) and *spaghetti* (red line) to include *macaroni* (green line), *noodles* (yellow line), and *vermicelli* (dark blue line) over the period 1900–2019 yields an interesting set of line plots:

[image]

The most surprising thing to me about this chart is the relative newness of the word *noodles*: in 1900, the only word of the four track that had any significant frequency of usage in published work was *macaroni*.

A search through US English dictionaries yields some insight into which words were in use when and with what meanings.

Published only a few decades after the heyday of "Yankee Doodle," Noah Webster's *A Compendious Dictionary of the English Language* (1806) has this entry for *macaroni*:

> ***Macaroni**, n. a fop, fribble, finical fellow, paste

The same dictionary devotes no space to *paste* in the specific sense of something edible:

> **Paste**, n. a thick mixture of solids and fluids, a cement

Sounds yummy. Neither *spaghetti* nor *noodle* has any entry in the 1806 *Compendious Dictionary*, but to my surprise, there is an entry for *vermicelli*:

> **Vermicelli,** *n.* a paste made like threds, a soop.

Webster's much larger *An American Dictionary of the English Language* (1828) has nothing for *spaghetti*, but the other four words are at least mentioned, although only one seems much related to *pasta* in the modern sense:

> **MACARONI,** *n.* {It. *maccheroni*, a sort of paste ; Fr. *macaroni* ; Gr. μαχαρ, happy.} *1.* A kind of biscuit made of flour, eggs, sugar, and almonds, and dressed with butter and spices. *B. Jonson* **2.** A sort of droll or fool, and hence, a fop ; a fribble ; a finical fellow.
>
> **NOODLE,** *n.* A simpleton. {*A vulgar word.*}
>
> **PASTE,** *n.* {Fr. *pâte*, for *paste* ; It. Sp. *pasta*. Qu. L. *pistus* or Gr. πασσω, to sprinkle, or some root which signifies to mix and knead.} 1. A soft composition of substances, as flour moistened with water or milk and kneaded, or any kind of earth moistened and formed to the consistency of dough. *Paste* made of flour is used in cookery ; *paste* made of flour or earth, is used in various arts and manufactures, as cement.
>
> **VERMICELLI,** *n.* {It. *vermicello*, a little worm, from *vermis*, a worm.} In *cookery*, little rolls or threads of paste, or a composition of flour, eggs, sugar and saffron ; used in soups and pottages.

*An American Dictionary of the English Language* (1847)—the first Merriam Brothers version of Webster's Dictionary exhibits a much clearer idea than its predecessors did of *macaroni* as pasta:

> **MACARONI,** *n.* ... **1.** Dough of whet flour made into a tubular or pipe form, of the thickness of a goose quill ; Italian or Genoese paste. ...

*Paste*, too, receives more detailed treatment in its relevant senses:

> **PASTE,** *n.* ... **1.** A soft composition of substances, as flour moistened with water or milk and kneaded, or any kind of earth moistened and formed into the consistence of dough, as in making potter's ware. **2.** A kind of cement made of flour and water boiled, used for uniting paper or other substances

But *noodle* is still only a simpleton, vermicelli is still associated with "a composition of flour, eggs, sugar and saffron," and *spaghetti* is nowhere to be found.

The last of the three major editions of *An American Dictionary of the English language* (1864) is the first to define *vermicelli* in the pasta sense that people today are familiar with:

> *Vermicelli,* n. ... The flour of a hard and small grained wheat made into dough, and forced through slender cylinders or pipes till it takes a slender, worm-like form, whence the Italian name.

*Noodle* finally makes the grade as a foodstuff in *Webster's International Dictionary* (1890):

> **Noodle,** *n.* {G. *nudel* vermicelli.} A thin strip of dough, made with eggs, rolled up, cut into small pieces, and used in soup.

Spaghetti debuts in the same dictionary, with this entry:

> **Spaghetti** *n.* {It.} A variety of macaroni made in tubes of small diameter.

And the entry for *vermicelli*, after repeating the definition from the 1864 *An American Dictionary* adds this note about how to distinguish between *vermicelli* and *macaroni*:

> When the paste is made in larger tubes, it is called *macaroni*.

As of *Webster's First Collegiate Dictionary* (1898), this is where the relevant definitions stand:

> **Macaroni** *n.* **1.** Long slender tubes made of a paste chiefly of wheat flour, and used as food.
>
> **Noodle** *n.* Dough, made with eggs, cut into small pieces, and used in soup.
>
> **Paste** *n.* **1.** A soft composition, as of moistened flour or earth. **2.** Specif., in cookery, pastry dough.
>
> **Spaghetti,** *n.* A variety of macaroni made in tubes of small diameter.
>
> Vermicelli, n. Wheat flour made into a slender wormlike form : — whence the Italian name.

At least in the United States, *macaroni*, *paste*, and *vermicelli* appear in dictionaries in the context of food as far back as 1806. *Noodle* and *spaghetti* follow in 1890. But of the five words tracked in the Google Ngram above, none seems particularly negatively affected by the rise of pasta. Instead, their frequencies since 1970 seem to have risen slightly, though at a much less impressive trajectory than *pasta* has. And when you add *paste* (pink line) to the mix, just to see whether its frequency dropped as pasta's rose, you find that it rose too between 1970 and 2010:

[image]

So the rise of *pasta* seems, above all, to be due to an increase in interest in foods of the pasta group, not due to a zero-sum change in popularity of one term at the expense of another.

Still, you may wonder why English speakers jumped aboard the *pasta* train when they had a perfectly good English word (*paste*) that could be (and for many years had been) used to refer to the same generic category of starchy foods. One answer, surely, is that *pasta* arose not in the context of all noodle-like starches, but in the context of the specifically Italian subset of such starches—their *abbondanza* notwithstanding.

A second, more speculative answer relates to what I call "commercial correctness": companies are very keen not to have sales of their products hurt by issues of nomenclature. This is evident in such changes in food wordings as *mahi-mahi* (for *dolphin* [the fish, not the mammal], *orange roughy* (for *slimehead*), *chevon* (for *goat meat*), and *canola oil* (for *rapeseed oil*). It may be that purveyors of spaghetti- or macaroni-like foodstuffs felt that the generic term *paste* was sufficiently unappetizing to put a damper on public enthusiasm for the food category, whereas *pasta* sounded exotic, appealing, and unambiguously culinary.

Comment: are those n-gram graphs for US English? From the surrounding text being specific to US English I'd assume so, but it may be worth clarifying as usage here is very different between the US & UK today

Comment: The ngram for "paste" can be misleading because we also have paste foods that aren't pasta, such as "tomato paste".

Comment: @Barmer: The Ngram for _paste_ is rife with complicating variables, including _paste_ as a glue alternative, _paste_ as a consistency description, _paste_ as a fake gem, and _paste_ as a verb. The only reason I included it at all (in the second Ngram chart was to show that there was no appreciable decline in the multitude of uses of _paste_ during the period (1970–2010 when _pasta_ went from uncommon to quite common in English publications. So unless there was a countervailing increase in some other use of _paste_ that masked its loss to _pasta_, it wasn't much affected by that word's rise.

Comment: @Tristan: The Ngrams included in my answer reflect undifferentiated English language sources. The one for American English only, which you can see [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pasta%2Cspaghetti%2Cmacaroni%2Cnoodles%2Cvermicelli%2Cpaste&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3), is slightly different, but not much. The Ngram for British English, shown [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pasta%2Cspaghetti%2Cmacaroni%2Cnoodles%2Cvermicelli%2Cpaste&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3), is more obviously different.

Comment: _it rose too between 1970 and 20010_ 18 thousand years in the future! Impressive!

Comment: @CJDennis: Thanks for pointing out the typo.

Comment: @SvenYargs Also as a description for certain types of badly-cooked food. "Paste" would be a turn-off.

Comment: Chevon vs goat isn't political correctness, it comes from the same idea as cow vs beef which is an artifact of the Normans winning the battle of Hastings and all the French words that came with it.  But goat derived products are fairly rare in the US so in almost all cases (with the exception of fancy restaurants) it is simply called goat meat.  Cheese is more mixed between goat cheese and chevre though.

Comment: Don't forget the use of *paste* in computer terminology over the last 3 decades or so.

Comment: @PM2Ring Copy pasta leads to spaghetti code.

Comment: @eps: I mentioned _chevon_ as an example of commercially correct speech because it appears to have been a word specifically invented (in English) to avoid consumers' negative attitudes toward "goat meat"—specifically older, stronger-flavored goat meat. The new word was supposed to avoid the unpleasant associations of the old term. I wrote an EL&U answer [focused on the derivation of _chevon_](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167738/why-is-mutton-used-for-both-sheep-meat-and-goat-meat/167775#167775) back in 2014.

Comment: @SvenYargs In *Webster’s Third New International Dictionary of the English Language, Unabridged*  (principal copyright 1961) an entry for *pasta* appears with these two senses: “**1 :** alimentary paste in processed form (as spaghetti or macaroni) or in the form of fresh dough (as ravioli) **2 :** a dish of cooked pasta”. // They give for its stressed vowel that of FATHER as we still say today here, not that of TRAP as heard in the UK (let alone of FACE said by no one). My copy is 1981’s *… and Seven Language Dictionary* printing in case that matters, although I suspect it does not.

Comment: Looks like your ngram photo has disappeared/broken. (Perhaps has to do with imgur's change to TOC?)

Answer (score 5):

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pasta%2Cspaghetti&year_start=1920&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) suggests it was around 1980.

[image]

Comment: I woulda said it was “in the ‘70s”

Comment: "pasta" is a general term, whereas "spaghetti" is a particular shape of pasta. I grew up in an Italian-American family, and in the '40s and 50s, even into the '60s, all shapes were referred to as "macaroni" although current definitions have macaroni as a particular shape. Wikipedia says that some Italian-American groups are known to have used "macaroni" as a general term. My Sicilian grandmother and my Neapolitan grandfather never used the word "pasta" unless they were talking about pasta e fagioli. Usually we referred to each shape specifically. How it was in the old country I don't know.

Comment: This answers the *when* part of the question, but not the *why* part. A reasonable hypothesis is that it is around that time that the supermarkets and restaurants in English-speaking countries started offering a wider range of different kinds of pasta, which on one side, created a greater awareness of the differences among them, and on the other, created the need for a term that encompasses them all.

Comment: Among the books I inherited from my aunt is a book on Italian cookery originally published in 1958, when Mediterranean food was just beginning to be widely known in the UK. The section 'Pasta' explains _The Italian term 'pasta' covers a multitude of various shapes and forms of what we tend to lump together in our minds under the heading of 'macaroni' or 'spaghetti'._ Like Jim, I remember it as being the late 60s/early 70s  that interest in foreign cuisine really took off.

Answer (score 1):

Supposedly, *pasta salad* and *pasta primavera* became [popular menu items](https://www.grubstreet.com/2015/01/80s-dining-trends-new-york-city.html) in the early 80s, which was also reflected in [pop culture](https://mirror80.com/2018/12/80s-restaurant-food-trends/).

> Don’t forget the wide range of ’80s movies that reflect ’80s food trends, such as the above-mentioned Baby Boom, as well as Wall Street, which sees Charlie Sheen’s character enjoying an over-the-top apartment redesign, complete with a fully-stocked kitchen that includes yuppie staples like a sushi maker and a **pasta maker** (see images above and below).

Anecdotally, based on the comments

> [T]he reason we ate so much pasta and bread is that fat, not carbs, was the big health scare at the time. Everyone tried to eat low or no fat. We didn’t even distinguish between good and bad fats. For example, butter was considered bad for you (due to fat and cholesterol), so we all used margarine, which turned out to be worse for us.

Comment: But we just called it oleo.

Comment: @Jim, I'm not sure where you're from, but in California the word *oleo* was long gone by the 1980's. I don't remember ever encountering it (except as a crossword puzzle word) in my lifetime (which goes back to the 1970's).

Comment: @ThePhoton -  I go back a little farther than that but I guess picked it up from my parents.  I can also say that many called it margarine during that same time period.

Comment: @Jim My mom still said "oleo" when I was growing up in the 1990s (U.S. Midwest). But I seem to recall that there was a distinction: oleo comes in a stick and you use it for baking; margarine comes in a tub and you spread it on bread. Maybe that was because she was working from *her* mother's recipes, which would have called it "oleo." This might be worth its own question!

Comment: @Jim Oleo is short for oleomargarine. Wikipedia's article is very interesting: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margarine]

Comment: "Supposedly, pasta salad and pasta primavera became popular menu items in the early 80s" But why were they called "pasta" and not "macaroni" or "noodle" salad/primavera?